# Start reasoner is not enabled in Protege menu

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege

I created entities, classes, object properties and all in protege(4.3.0) but the start reasoner item in the menu is disabled. Do i need to do anything to active start reasoner?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Did you select a reasoner?

Comment: i just go to protege and create entities etc according to youtube tutorial in that tutorial he do start reasoner but its disable in my protege window

Comment: If you're trying to follow some YouTube tutorial, please link to it.  Until you do, we don't have any idea what you're talking about.

Comment: [youtube protege tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaepddOkv4g) in 4.28 minute

Comment: At 4:28, notice that there are three items in the Reasoner menu at the bottom: **FaCT++**, **HermiT 1.3.8**, and **None**.  In the video, **HermiT 1.3.8** is selected.  You have to select one of the reasoners before you can do **Start Reasoner**.

Comment: thanx a lot i got the point :) can u tell me what is the different between FaCT++, HermiT 1.3.8?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer that the problem is the menu item being /disabled/ rather than /not working/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this [tutorial on YouTube, 4:28](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaepddOkv4g), notice that there are three items in the **Reasoner** menu at the bottom: **FaCT++**, **HermiT 1.3.8**, and **None**. In the video, **HermiT 1.3.8** is selected. You have to select one of the reasoners before you can do **Start Reasoner**.  FaCT++ and HermiT are just different OWL reasoners.  Pellet is another that you can use with Protégé, although you'll have to install the plugin.